# A strange access violation error

Tags: c++, access-violation

I have wrote a program that use inheritance, everything is OK but an error that I think shouldn't not be here naturally.
here is my program:

```
class A
{
protected:
    int x;
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){};
    A* operator=(const A* other)
    {
        this->x = other->x;
        return this;
    }
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(){};
    ~B(){};
};
class C
{
protected:
    A *a;
public:
    C(const A* other){ *(this->a) = other; };
};

int main()
{
    B *b = new B();
    C *c = new C(b);
    return 0;
}
```

It produces an execution time error in the statement 'this->x = other->x;'.
What about this?

Comment: Your assignment operator should be returning `A&`, not `A*`

Comment: More important that it should take `const A &` as an argument. Now one may think that `0` is allowed as an argument (particularly compiler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Luchian's answer but there is still some places to enhanced in your code, you may still encounter some undefined behavior in your code before you fix other potential bugs.

```
class A
{
protected:
    int x;
public:
    A():x(0){}     // should always initialize x in constructor
    virtual ~A()=0 {} // as A is a base case, ~A must be virtual
    A& operator=(const A& other)  // a reference will be more practical better?
    {
        this->x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

If you don't want to make B object as well which means B is serviced as a base class, you should make its destructor virtual as well, even make it pure virtual.

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(){}
    virtual ~B(){} =0
    { }       
};
```

`*(this->a) = other;` is answered by Luchian already. In your code, if you want to keep a copy of pointer which points to A, you can simply initialize a_ptr in `member initialize list`
see below demo code:

```
class C
{
protected:
   A *a_ptr;
public:
    C(A* other):a_ptr(other){ }
};
```

Finally come to your main function, if b,c are only used in main function, when program finishes, system will claim dynamic allocated memory back, but if you use `a,b` in a loop, you need to delete them manually.

Answer (score 7):

`*(this->a)` is undefined behavior, because `this->a` wasn't initialized - it's just a dangling pointer.

You can use `a = new A; *a = other` (the `this->` in this case is redundant), but this isn't the proper C++ way - you should use RAII (look it up) - you wouldn't need destructors, assignment operators or copy constructors if you did.

Also, `operator =` typically returns `*this` by reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are right. But I have a problem yet. In my real program, `A` is an abstract class and I can't make an `A` object, and I don't want to make a `B` object too! I need `A` behave like an abstract class for derived classes like `B`. There may be more derived classes, yet. Could I clarify my problem?

Comment: "Also, operator = typically returns *this by reference" ...and takes `const A & other` as an argument.

Comment: @doc you're thinking of a *copy* assignment operator. You can have assignment operators that take any parameter, so that's not really an issue.

Comment: @JalalJaberi I understand what you mean, then just use `new B` instead (or whatever class is there). If you don't know the type of the class, you can use rtti.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore see what this assignment operator is doing: `this->x = other->x;`... and think what will happen if other is null.